# How to run TensorFlow GPU version on Google Colab with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow1.15

I have a code written using the **TensorFlow version 1.15** for an image to image translation task and I want to run it on Google Colab environment which currently has Python 3.10.12 installed by default.

Due to my source code's dependencies, I have to use TensorFlow version 1.15 and that's why I have used other dependencies that match with this version of TensorFlow.

First, I install Python version 2.7 on Google Colab using the command below:

```
!apt-get install python2
```

After that, I check the installed Python's version:

```
!python2 --version
```

And I get: Python **2.7.18**

Next, I connect to Google Drive and refer to the path where my source is located (**main.py, util.py, model.py and ops.py**):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/TFCode/
```

Then to install the necessary packages, first I install pip using the commands below:

```
!curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
!python2 get-pip.py
```

And then:

```
!python2 -m pip install six
!python2 -m pip install scipy
!python2 -m pip install imageio==2.4.1
!apt-get install build-essential
!python2 -m pip install grpcio==1.26.0
!python2 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
!python2 -m pip install opencv-python==3.4.8.29
!python2 -m pip install scikit-image==0.14.5
```

Finally, I run my source using `!python2 main.py` and despite the fact that the code runs successfully, it takes a long time to finish the task becuase my code is not being run on GPU and I know this because of the following code block inside my **main.py** file:

```
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Inside my results, I see the "Please install GPU version of TF" string output which means the GPU cannot be detected but when I run this code like below directly in Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

I get this: **Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0** which means it finds the GPU but as this code is being run directly in Colab environment, I know that it uses Python 3.10.12 and TensorFlow version 2.

How can I run my own source code with GPU?

Using version 2.7 of Python is not a must but version 1.15 of TensorFlow must be used and other dependencies must match with this version of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Note: there is a TensorFlow GPU 1.15 is [compatible with Python 3.9-3.11](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). [TensorFlow 1.15](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.5/) (Jan. 2020) is no longer listed.

> Using version 2.7 of Python is not a must

Since TensorFlow 1.15 is compatible with Python 3.7, you try and create a virtual environment with Python 3.7 instead, avoiding any compatibility issue with Python 2:

```py
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!python3.7 -m venv tf15env
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```py
!source /content/tf15env/bin/activate
```

And install TensorFlow 1.15 and other dependencies within the virtual environment:

```py
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
!pip install six scipy imageio==2.4.1 grpcio==1.26.0 opencv-python==3.4.8.29 scikit-image==0.14.5
```

Run this script to make sure TensorFlow is using the GPU:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

After setting up the environment, you can run your code (`main.py`, `util.py`, `model.py`, `ops.py`) in this virtual environment.

---

See also "[Changing the Python version on Google Colab](https://medium.com/the-owl/changing-the-python-version-on-google-colab-245fd510d3ae)" from [Siladittya Manna](https://sadimanna.github.io) for an alternative way to change the Python version on Google Colab.

Comment: When I run `!python3.7 -m venv tf15env`, I get this error: Error: Command '['/content/tf15env/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Check if python 3.7 is installed or not. If not: `!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-venv -y`

Comment: Thanks I did that and I also ran `!python3.7 -m pip install protobuf==3.20.0` to make the notebook work with my source codes' packages but I still can't utilize the GPU for some reason.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Can you update your question with all the commands you used, and any error message you might still have?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the guide ["Changing the Python version on Google Colab"](https://medium.com/the-owl/changing-the-python-version-on-google-colab-245fd510d3ae) from [Siladittya Manna](https://sadimanna.github.io/) stated by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) and everything seems to work. I used Colab with an T4 GPU instance.

```bash
!apt-get update -y
!apt-get install python3.7 python3.7-distutils
!update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!update-alternatives --config python3
!apt-get install python3-pip
!python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

```bash
!python3 --version # Python 3.7.17
```

With the install instruction already mentioned by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc):

```bash
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15
!pip install six scipy imageio==2.4.1 grpcio==1.26.0 opencv-python==3.4.8.29 scikit-image==0.14.5
```

Including your version dependency for protobuf:

```bash
!pip install protobuf==3.20.0
```

Running

```py
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

I get **Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0**.

Comment: Okay that's weird. I tried the check with `main.py` and I get the same error as you.